# How to select patches from an agentset with no turtles?

Tags: netlogo

So this is the code I feel justified with:

```
let movable-patches ( [ neighbors ] of selected-turtle with [not (any? other turtles-here)])
```

I want to get an `agentset` of `patches` neighbouring the `selected-turtle` (which is a `turtle` object) and these neighbors should not have `turtles-here`.

But, it gives me a run-time error:

```
WITH expected input to be an agentset but got NOBODY instead.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bracketing issue. Here is a complete model that demonstrates the fixed code.

```
to testme
  clear-all
  create-turtles 10
  [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set color blue
  ]
  selection
end

to selection
  let selected-turtle one-of turtles
  ask selected-turtle [set color red]
  let movable-patches ([ neighbors ] of selected-turtle) with [not (any? other turtles-here)]
  ask movable-patches [ set pcolor red ]
end
```

I have the brackets like this: `([ neighbors ] of selected-turtle)`. You have them surrounding `[ neighbors ] of selected-turtle with [not (any? other turtles-here)]`. The problem is that `with` is a high precedence operator and goes first (like multiply is done before addition). So you are effectively asking NetLogo to find `selected-turtle with [not (any? other turtles-here)]` and then take the `neighbors` of that.

Comment: Ah, I see! Where can I get details like precedences, return types and all? NetLogo Docs contains only dictionary and Programming Guide.

Comment: Dictionary is the syntax for all the primitives. Precedence is in the Programming Guide.